# I'm wondering how to use the wait_for command correctly. Anyone can help me out? its discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, command

I'm trying to make the bot say Correct, or Incorrect when I answer the question. But, the bot wouldn't say Correct nor Incorrect.

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
class Trivia(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client```

    @commands.command()
    async def Trivia(self, ctx):
        question = ['Who invented The Theory of Special Relavity?',
                    'Who created Algebra?',
                    "What is Newton's third law? **use 'and' instead of '&'**",
                    'Who discover prism?']
        responses = ['Albert Einstein',
                     'al-Khwarizmi',
                     'Action and Reaction',
                     'Isaac Newton']
        await ctx.send('**Welcome to this Trivia! There will be 5 questions that you have to answer.**')
        await ctx.send(f'Question: {question[0]}')
        async def on_message(self, message):
            if self.message.content.wait_for('Albert Einstein'):
                await self.channel.send('Correct!')
            else:
                self.channel.send('Incorrect!')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Trivia(client))
````

after changes:

````
        await ctx.send(f'Question: {question[0]}')
        await ctx.wait_for('Albert Einstein')
        await self.channel.send('Correct!')
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Trivia(client))```
and then it shows this error : ```AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'wait_for'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:```
````

Comment: there is an example in the discord.py docs ;) [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: You can't mix a command and an event.... You must use a `await xxx.wait_for('message')` statement

Comment: It's not `ctx.wait_for`, it's `self.client.wait_for`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wait for a message you use `self.client.wait_for('message')`.

*Here is then also an example from the docs: [Bot.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)*

Also little sense makes `{question[0]}`, because then always only the first question is taken.
To create a mix you should select a question from `question` with `random.choice(question)`. The difficult part here will be to wait for the correct answer/choose it since you use two lists, needs some code.

To ask all the questions one by one we use `for i in question`.

**I have created a small example for you, maybe it will help you:**

```py
@commands.command()
async def trivia(self, ctx):
    def check(m): # Checks that the author of the command gives the answer
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('**Welcome to this Trivia! There will be 5 questions that you have to answer.**')

    question = ['Who invented The Theory of Special Relavity?',
                'Who created Algebra?',
                "What is Newton's third law? **use 'and' instead of '&'**",
                'Who discover prism?']
    responses = ['Albert Einstein',
                 'al-Khwarizmi',
                 'Action and Reaction',
                 'Isaac Newton']

    for i in question:
        await ctx.send(i) # Send the question

        try:
            await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check) # Wait for the message
            # Your event that checks if the answer is correct
        except:
            return
```

Comment: omg this helps me so much, thanks for helping by!

Comment: @VerxtunBS You are welcome. If this helped you with your question, then feel free to accept the answer, in case others stumble upon the same problem they will directly see that my answer helped.

Comment: sorry I just test it again and it shows this error AttributeError: module 'cogs.trivia' has no attribute 'setup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Im sorry @Dominik im a retard, and i havent set the client for cogs. Im sorry!

Comment: @VerxtunBS Yes, this is just the command with the `wait_for` "event" you were asking for.

Comment: How do I accept the answer? Sorry I'm new in this community

Comment: @VerxtunBS Just click on the checkmark next to my answer.